# wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) in Warden::SessionSerializer#administrator_deserialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

In my project I want to use Devise with STI. I have classes that looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Administrator < User
end
```

In my routes I  have:

```
  devise_for :administrators
```

When I visit /administrators/sign_up or /administrators/sign_in it returns me following error:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

block (2 levels) in Warden::SessionSerializer#administrator_deserialize
devise (3.5.6) lib/devise.rb, line 464
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 devise_for :administrators, skip: :sessions #should resolve the issue
```

Comment: A little more explanation of *how* and *why* this fixes the issue would be helpful.